# Best model for rise-and-fall dynamics (sales of new product)?

Tags: time-series, survival, econometrics, model, epidemiology

Imagine new product hitting the market, sales dynamically rise, achieve plateau, and then steadily drop. I'm thinking of something with dynamics that when depicted on a plot (counts over time), will resemble Little Prince's drawing of snake who ate an elephant (well, maybe with less extreme drop at the end).

[image]

What would be the best model for such process? I imagine I could find some interesting hints in epidemiological models -- if yes, could you suggest something? I'm looking for something relatively simple, using just counts over time as data.

Comment: Something simple would be like a polynomial (Koyck or Almon) distributed lag model with a dead start effect.

Comment: The textbook is the [Bass sales diffusion model.  ](https://faculty.biu.ac.il/~fruchtg/829/lec/6.pdf).  Variations on mixtures are used by big folks in order to have multiple sequential new products - to truncate sales of last years cars and improve sales of this years cars.